# Create hierarchical clustering heatmap based on grouping?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, group-by

I'm trying to create **heatmap** like the image below where the **right side color bar** is in **4 groups**: `Control > Rv, Ra`; `Rv> Ra > Control`; `Ra > Control > Rv`; `Ra > Rv > Control`
The heatmap was performed with Euclidean distance matrices mean-centered and log base 2 transformed **FPKM normalized**. How can I  create the heatmap looking like they were *arranged* **based** on *aforementioned grouping*?

[image: image source: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-40814-0#Fig2]

Example FPKM table; note that the data is 85 rows x 3 columns in reality

| gene | Control | Ra | Rv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cyp27a1 | 32.681000 | 4.52616 | 13.3868 |
| Serpinb2 | 1.611980 | 513.10400 | 20.7699 |
| Rab7b | 118.964000 | 20.78690 | 43.3432 |
| Ptgs2 | 0.328475 | 371.33000 | 29.0941 |
| Mgat4a | 6.680070 | 70.09530 | 25.931 |
| Acsl1 | 15.459900 | 431.43400 | 186.2550 |
| Gas6 | 82.042200 | 8.39169 | 17.3220 |
| Bcl2a1a | 4.162480 | 395.83800 | 99.9439 |
| Zc3h12c | 7.454010 | 43.01970 | 18.7162 |
| Bcl2a1d | 15.641200 | 440.34900 | 109.8670 |

Here's what I have done so far:

```
df.set_index('gene', inplace=True)
df[['Control', 'Ra','Rv']] = df_deg[['Control', 'Ra','Rv']].add(1).apply(np.log2) # FPKM +1 and log transformed
df_cent = df.apply(lambda x:x-x.mean()) # mean centered

## Heatmap ##
map_plt= sns.clustermap(df_cent, metric="euclidean", cmap="RdBu_r", vmin=-8, vmax=6, 
               xticklabels=True, yticklabels=False)
map_plt.ax_col_dendrogram.set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Mine looked like this:
[image]

I had to expand the min and max otherwise it looks like a giant red block.
Also did I do the mean-centered and log2 transformation correctly?
Thank you.

Comment: To add color indications on the rows, the clustermap has a `row_colors=` option.   [The documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html) contains an example (although it might be a bit complicated to understand if you aren't super fluid with Python).  Also note that you can set `sns.clustermap(..., col_cluster=False)` to directly leave out the clustering of the columns.  See also [Setting col_colors from pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334796) and [additional row colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173798).

Comment: Since the rows are 'sorted' by defined condition, mentioned in the post, wouldn't I need to arrange the data first? I don't think I can define conditionals in the `row_colors`

Answer (score 1):

The `row_colors` need to be given in the original order. Seaborn will then recalculate the order to coincide with the row reordering by the dendrogram.
You can create them by iterating through the columns.

Here is an example of how it could work in your situation. Please check whether the conditions need to use `df_cent` or `df`. You might want to adjust the positioning of the different elements.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import TwoSlopeNorm
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74980890')[0]

df = df.set_index('gene')
df[['Control', 'Ra', 'Rv']] = df[['Control', 'Ra', 'Rv']].add(1).apply(np.log2)  # FPKM +1 and log transformed
df_cent = df.apply(lambda x: x - x.mean())  # mean centered

legend_labels = ['Control > Rv, Ra', 'Rv > Ra > Control', 'Ra > Control > Rv', 'Ra > Rv > Control']
legend_colors = ['gold', 'crimson', 'limegreen', 'cornflowerblue', 'black']
row_colors = [legend_colors[0] if Control > Rv and Control > Ra else  # or maybe 'Control > Rv or Control > Ra' ????
              legend_colors[1] if Rv > Ra > Control else
              legend_colors[2] if Ra > Control > Rv else
              legend_colors[3] if Ra > Rv > Control else
              legend_colors[4]
              for Control, Ra, Rv in zip(df_cent['Control'], df_cent['Ra'], df_cent['Rv'])]

norm = TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=0, vmin=-8, vmax=6)
g = sns.clustermap(df_cent, metric="euclidean", cmap="RdBu_r", norm=norm,
                   xticklabels=True, yticklabels=False,
                   dendrogram_ratio=(0.25, 0.15),  # fraction of the figure dedicated to row and column dendrograms
                   row_colors=row_colors,
                   col_cluster=False,
                   cbar_pos=[.4, .95, .5, .03],  # x, y, width, height in "figure coordinates"
                   cbar_kws={'orientation': "horizontal"})
# create a legend, use the row dendogram for positioning
legend_handles = [plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 0, 0, color=color, label=label)
                  for color, label in zip(legend_colors, legend_labels)]
g.ax_row_dendrogram.legend(title='Row Colors', handles=legend_handles, loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.02))
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.clustermap with row colors]